# MongoDB: output 'id' instead of '_id'

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose (node), what is the best way to output id instead of _id?

Comment: For new readers: below you will see multiple *different* approaches. It is wise to read them all before choosing, instead of blindly going for accepted or most votes. Cheers!

Comment: `Brands.find(query).project({ _id: 0, id: '$_id', name: 1 }).toArray()`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I create a toClient() method on my models where I do this. It's also a good place to rename/remove other attributes you don't want to send to the client:

```
Schema.method('toClient', function() {
    var obj = this.toObject();

    //Rename fields
    obj.id = obj._id;
    delete obj._id;

    return obj;
});
```

Comment: I really new to mongoose, this does seem like what I want. how do you call this toClient? Normally I do, find(), and get a docs object back, then just do res.send(docs). So in this case, do I call res.write(docs[1].toClient()) on each doc? thanks

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me now - has the method of doing this in Mongoose changed?

Comment: virtuals is probably what you want.

Answer (score 138):

Given you're using Mongoose, you can use 'virtuals', which are essentially fake fields that Mongoose creates. They're not stored in the DB, they just get populated at run time:

```
// Duplicate the ID field.
Schema.virtual('id').get(function(){
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

// Ensure virtual fields are serialised.
Schema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});
```

Any time toJSON is called on the Model you create from this Schema, it will include an 'id' field that matches the _id field Mongo generates. Likewise you can set the behaviour for toObject in the same way.

See:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html
- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON
- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject

You can abstract this into a BaseSchema all your models then extend/invoke to keep the logic in one place. I wrote the above while creating an Ember/Node/Mongoose app, since Ember really prefers to have an 'id' field to work with.

Comment: Very good solution (+1). I would also add `Schema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true })` to be able to see virtuals in output when using `console.log(obj)`.

Comment: This keeps the _id field. I prefer the transform solution instead, the one provided by shakinfree worked for me.

Comment: 'toJson' is only when converting to JSON. The more general approach would be to use `toObject`. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject

Comment: I was placed it in model, it does not runs, where can I place it? placed under this `const companyCollection = mongoose.Schema({});` using ExpressJs

Comment: In the latest version of Mongoose (5.4.20 at this time) there is a virtual `id` getter included/prebuilt in the API. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id

Comment: I keep coming back to this answer :))

Comment: I get the following error when I try this soluction `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toHexString')`

Answer (score 58):

As of Mongoose **v4.0** part of this functionality is **supported out of the box**. It's no longer required to manually add a virtual `id` field as explained by @Pascal Zajac.

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default
>   which returns the documents _id field cast to a string, or in the case
>   of ObjectIds, its hexString. If you don't want an id getter added to
>   your schema, you may disable it passing this option at schema
>   construction time. [Source](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id)

However, to **export** this field to **JSON**, it's still required to **enable** serialization of virtual fields:

```
Schema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});
```

Comment: This was true long before v4.0, but what the OP wants is for *just* id (and not _id) to be returned. Just telling mongoose to include the virtual id returns both.

Comment: What if you have other virtuals you want to exclude?

Answer (score 58):

I used this :

```
schema.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true,
  versionKey:false,
  transform: function (doc, ret) {   delete ret._id  }
});
```

I think it would be great if they automatically suppress _id when virtuals is true.

Comment: This one worked for me.  Where schema is each model you create.  For example:

`const UserSchema = new Schema({ stuff });

UserSchema.set("toJSON", {
  virtuals: true,
  versionKey: false,
  transform: function(doc, ret) {
    delete ret._id;
  }
});

const User = model("user", UserSchema);`

Comment: If anyone finds this isn't working for them straight away, check that you're not using `lean: true` option when retrieving your documents from the database.

Comment: Document versioning can also be disabled by setting the versionKey to false. DO NOT disable versioning unless you know what you are doing.
http://aaronheckmann.blogspot.com/2012/06/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning.html
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey

Comment: what is the 'doc', that we are passing to the function? whats the content of it?

Answer (score 35):

Here is an alternative version of the answer provided by @user3087827. If you find that `schema.options.toJSON` is undefined then you can use:

```
schema.set('toJSON', {
     transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
         ret.id = ret._id;
         delete ret._id;
         delete ret.__v;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 26):

```
//Transform
Schema.options.toJSON.transform = function (doc, ret, options) {
  // remove the _id of every document before returning the result
  ret.id = ret._id;
  delete ret._id;
  delete ret.__v;
}
```

there is a "Schema.options.toObject.transform" property to do the reverse or you could just setup as a virtual id.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to use `id` instead of `_id` **globally** then you can set `toJSON` config on mongoose object([starting from v5.3](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6815)):

```js
mongoose.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true,
  transform: (doc, converted) => {
    delete converted._id;
  }
});
```

Comment: @151291 This is working. Ensure you don't use lean.

Answer (score 10):

There is also [`normalize-mongoose`](https://npmjs.com/normalize-mongoose) a simple package that removes `_id` and `__v` for you.

From something like this:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import normalize from 'normalize-mongoose';

const personSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String });

personSchema.plugin(normalize);

const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
const someone = new Person({ name: 'Abraham' });
const result = someone.toJSON();

console.log(result);
```

So let's say you have something like this:

```
{
  "_id": "5dff03d3218b91425b9d6fab",
  "name": "Abraham",
  "__v": 0
}
```

You will get this output:

```
{
  "id": "5dff03d3218b91425b9d6fab",
  "name": "Abraham"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Overwrite default method `toJSON` by new one:

```
schema.method('toJSON', function () {
   const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
   object.id = _id;
   return object;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I created an easy to use [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meanie-mongoose-to-json) for this purpose that I apply for all my projects and to all schema's globally. It converts `_id` to `id` and strips the `__v` parameter as well.

So it converts:

```
{
  "_id": "400e8324a71d4410b9dc3980b5f8cdea",
  "__v": 2,
  "name": "Item A"
}
```

To a simpler and cleaner:

```
{
  "id": "400e8324a71d4410b9dc3980b5f8cdea",
  "name": "Item A"
}
```

Usage as a global plugin:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.plugin(require('meanie-mongoose-to-json'));
```

Or for a specific schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const MySchema = new Schema({});
MySchema.plugin(require('meanie-mongoose-to-json'));
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the aggregate function when searching for items to return. $project will allow you to create fields, which you can do and assign it to _id.

```
<model>.aggregate([{$project: {_id: 0, id: '$_id'}], (err, res) => {
 // 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a base schema

```
import { Schema } from "mongoose";

    export class BaseSchema extends Schema {
        constructor(sche: any) {
            super(sche);
            this.set('toJSON', {
        virtuals: true,
        transform: (doc, converted) => {
            delete converted._id;
        }
    });
        }
    
    }
```

Now in your mongoose model, use `BaseSchema` instead of `Schema`

```
import mongoose, { Document} from 'mongoose';
import { BaseSchema } from '../../helpers/mongoose';

const UserSchema = new BaseSchema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,

});

export interface IUser {
    name: String,
    age: Number,

}

interface IPlanModel extends IUser, Document { }

export const PlanDoc = mongoose.model<IPlanModel>('User', UserSchema);
```

Typescript implementation of @Pascal Zajac answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lodash to pick the elements you want, this will work for you.

```
UserSchema.virtual('id').get(function(){
  return this._id.toHexString();
});

UserSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true })

UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  return _.pick( 
    this.toObject(), 
    ['id','email','firstName','lastName','username']
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `toJSON`method for specific model schema.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-method

```
YourSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  return {
    id: this._id,
    some_field: this.some_field,
    created_at: this.createdAt
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this config with `nestjs + mongoose` :

```
@Schema({ 
    versionKey: false, // __v field not saving to db
    timestamps: true,  // auto add both fields  'createdAt' and 'updatedAt'
    toJSON: {
        transform(doc, ret, options) {
            ret.id = ret._id;
            delete ret._id;
        },
    }
})
```

saved to database with this fields:

```
_id: 65b4df698bec4f57043f7bc3
email: "example@gmail.com"
password :"$argon2id$v"
role: "user"
```

response to client , id replaced with _id

```
id: 65b4df698bec4f57043f7bc3 // replaced with _id
email: "example@gmail.com"
password :"$argon2id$v"
role: "user"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another driver that does that http://alexeypetrushin.github.com/mongo-lite set `convertId` option to true. See "Defaults & Setting" section for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default which returns the document's _id field cast to a string, or in the case of ObjectIds, its hexString.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
const CartSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    products: [{
        productId: {
            type: String
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1
        },
    }]
}, {
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true,
        transform(doc, ret) {
            delete ret.__v
            delete ret.password
            ret.id = ret._id
            delete ret._id
        }
    }
})
```

1. Change _id to id: `ret.id = ret._id`
2. Delete _id:  `delete ret._id`

Method 2:

Answer (score -2):

You can also use pre 'save' hook:

```
TouSchema.pre('save', function () {      
  if (this.isNew) {
    this._doc.id = this._id;      
  } 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.toJSON()))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.