# Backbone.js sents POST instead of PUT (mongoose set _id to id)

Tags: backbone.js, mongoose

Backbone.js sents an POST on updated objects instead of an PUT.

I think this is because mongoDB uses _id instead of id.

**How do I say backbone.js to use _id instead of id?**

I already tried some server-side change but I think it would be easier just to say that backbone should use another attribute as id.
[MongoDB: output 'id' instead of '_id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034848/mongodb-output-id-instead-of-id)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the fine manual http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute

> **idAttribute** *model.idAttribute*
>
> A model's unique identifier is stored under the id attribute. If you're directly communicating with a
>   backend (CouchDB, MongoDB) that uses a different unique key, you may
>   set a Model's idAttribute to transparently map from that key to id.

Answer (score 0):

Id attribute can be changed per model like

```
var Meal = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "_id"
});
```

To make it default for all models (eg., if we are using mongodb), override the default setting by placing this LOC in your app js file that runs after backbone.js

```
//override the id attribute for model
Backbone.Model.prototype.idAttribute = '_id';
```