# Restify + MongoDB - Schema mapping

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, restify

I have a REST-API written in Restify (NodeJS). MongoDB is used as database (+ Mongoose).

I have a lot of collections, for each I created a schema. This is an example:

```
var UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
});
```

Now, for example, I want to map "_id" to "id", means, in the Request, the user should be able to write "id", which will then be mapped to "_id" and vice versa.

I want to separate the "REST-API-protocol" from the "Database-schema". What is the best practise to do so?

Comment: I recommend this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407567/mongoose-id-field-cant-be-deleted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoose "\_id" field can't be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407567/mongoose-id-field-cant-be-deleted)