# How to return data without _id when i use findByIdAndUpdate in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my code:

```
Task.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.task_id}, updateObj, {new: true}, function (err, updatedUser) {
            if (err) {
                return result.serverError(req, res)
            }
            result.success(req, res, updatedUser);
        });
```

It will return all fields,but i don't need '__v' and '_id',how should i do?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [mongoose-hidden](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-hidden) is your want.

You can also use the method in this link: [MongoDB: output 'id' instead of '_id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034848/mongodb-output-id-instead-of-id)

if you just want dismiss `__v`, you can use `versionKey` option for mogoose.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey

> Document versioning can also be disabled by setting the versionKey to
>   false. DO NOT disable versioning unless you know what you are doing.

```
new Schema({..}, { versionKey: false });
var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', schema);
var thing = new Thing({ name: 'no versioning please' });
thing.save(); // { name: 'no versioning please' }
```