# Mongoose change _id to id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to know how can i change the _id to id virtually or anyways so the direct json output from the database looks pretty. Additionally i see a __v generated in my documents and not sure how to hide those fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: output 'id' instead of '\_id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034848/mongodb-output-id-instead-of-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to hide __v in mongodb collection use **versionKey: false** in schema definition of collection.

**example:**

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

export class DeviceID extends mongoose.Schema {

    constructor() {
        super({
            device_id: String
        },
        {
            versionKey: false
        });
    }

}
```