# Property 'virtual' does not exist on type 'typeof Schema'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I am trying to change_id from mongoose schema to 'id' like is shown here [MongoDB: output 'id' instead of '_id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034848/mongodb-output-id-instead-of-id?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Duplicate the ID field.

```
Schema.virtual('id').get(function(){
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

// Ensure virtual fields are serialised.
Schema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});
```

I am using typescript and Schema does not seem to have a 'virtual' method nor a 'set' method, and keyword 'this' is not bound in this context either. Who knows their typescript equivalents?

Comment: Where are you getting your type definitions for mongoose from? The definitely typed v4 d.ts file does provide the 'virtual' function on the Schema type (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/v4/index.d.ts, line 740)

As for the 'this' context, you may need to specify the type within the function signature .get(function(this: any) { (or something more appropriate, if you know the type)

Comment: Found any solution? I'm facing the same issue for virtuals, the this worked for the inner function

Comment: Please, share us your code, where your `Schema` is beind declared

Comment: It seems to me that the Schema object you are trying to use is not of Mongoose. Please check if there is no other variable of same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed to work with inheritance

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

class BaseSchema extends Schema {
  constructor(args) {
    super();

    this.add(args);

    this.virtual('id').get(function(this: any) {
      return this._id.toHexString();
    });

    this.set('toObject', {
      virtuals: true,
    });

    this.set('toJSON', {
      virtuals: true,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me too. The benefit of it is that you can use it globally too. It's returning _id and id. For everyone who wants to have the id being returned only, one of the options would be to apply a transform function to the set('toJSON') method as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42763286/7372307