# Remove field from query mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My User model have name,..., password, resetToken, resetTokenExp property.

If I query user (findById, find({}),...), I want to drop password, resetToken and resetTokenExp field

```
User.findById(id)
  .select('-password -resetToken -resetTokenExp')  
  .exec()
```

I can use select but these fields are common ones and I dont want to type select everytime I query. How can I set remove these fields globally for User schema

Comment: Do not write find query many times, Just write once and reuse it with params.

Comment: Just ask to see if there is a 'global' way to do it. Thanks for your answer. Reuse the function is the best!

Comment: You can write a `post` event for `find` query and you can filter data on the model itself, but this will take unnecessary iterations.

Comment: Or you can write `pre` hook to filter queries on all find queries. this will be a simple and good solution but reuse function is a great choice because if you really want to get those excluded fields then you need to modify that event again

Comment: Good answer. Do you know how to make it return id instead of _id

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/7034848/2975952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make reusable functions something like this

so by default, these three fields will be excluded from the result

```
function fetchUser(id, exludeFields = { password: false, resetToken: false, resetTokenExp: false }) {
    return User.findById(id)
        .select(exludeFields)
        .exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you user Model Schema please refer below code.

You can use Mongoose Transform behavior [Link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject):

**Below code will help you to drop password, resetToken and resetTokenExp globally.**

And in this code you can also replacing **_id** with **id** globally.

***UserModel.js***

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String,
    resetToken: String,
    resetTokenExp: String

}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toObject: {
      transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.password;
        delete ret.resetToken
        delete ret.resetTokenExp
        return ret;
     }
   }
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```