# How to get id instead of _id Mongodb and use id as auto increment like 1,2,3,4?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

When I post data to the MongoDB database via node.js, id is generated like below

```
  {
            "_id": "619908d9b5ac0448fe368b35",
            "firstname": "ccccc",
            "createdAt": "2021-11-20T14:40:25.561Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-11-20T14:40:25.561Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
```

How can I change it like this

```
{
        "id": "1,
        "firstname": "ccccc",
        "createdAt": "2021-11-20T14:40:25.561Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-11-20T14:40:25.561Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: Every MongoDB record must have a field `_id`.  You can have field `id` too, but every record must have a field `_id`.  The field `_id` is special - it must be unique, and it is the only immutable field in MongoDB.  It can hold any data type except arrays.  I recommend you use it rather than adding another similar field called `id`.

Comment: This field `_id` is considered the primary key to the collection and will always have an index.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034848/mongodb-output-id-instead-of-id

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034848/mongodb-output-id-instead-of-id).